# Scroll Down Arrow Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

I'm working on a canvas drawing app and I  want to have a scroll down arrow show up in a div with a group of images to show the user that they have to scroll down to see the rest of the images, but also I want the user to be able to actually scroll down when touching the arrow. Could someone help me with the script to go about this ? thank you very much.

//////////////HTML/////////////////////////

```
<div id="branddraw">

 <div class="drawings col-md-2">

  <div class="pre-scrollable">



 <div class="thumb">
         <a class="thumbnail" href="#" id="img1">
         <img class="img-responsive" src="./assets/colour_imgs/Kcoloring/img1.png" alt="">
          </a>
 </div>
  <div class="thumb">
       <a class="thumbnail" href="#" id="img2">
       <img class="img-responsive"  src="./assets/colour_imgs/Kcoloring/img2.png" alt="">
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb">
     <a class="thumbnail" href="#" id="img3">
     <img class="img-responsive"  src="./assets/colour_imgs/Kcoloring/img3.png" alt="">
  </a>
   </div>


 <div class="thumb">
 <a class="thumbnail" href="#" id="img4">
<img class="img-responsive" src="./assets/colour_imgs/Kcoloring/img4.png" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumb">
   <a class="thumbnail" href="#" id="img5">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="./assets/colour_imgs/Kcoloring/img5.png" alt="">
   </a>
   </div>
  <div class="thumb">
 <a class="thumbnail" href="#" id="img6">
 <img class="img-responsive" src="./assets/colour_imgs/Kcoloring/img6.png" alt="">
  </a>
  </div>

          </div>

     </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: So where is your javascript/jQuery? What have you tried so far....

Comment: something along the lines as this                                                           $(function() {
 $('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 500, 'linear');
 });
});